# Unlinking a folder of files by async is super slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs, async.js

I am trying to call a http request which empty a folder by `fs`. We assume there is no sub-folders. Because `forEach` is not asynchronous, I choose to use the `each` of `async` rather than `forEach`. The code is as follows:

back-end:

```
router.post('/emptyDir', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.post /emptyDir");
    var dir = req.body.dir;
    var fs = require('fs');
    var async = require('async');
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
        async.each(files, function (file) {
            fs.unlink(dir + file, function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                console.log(dir + file + " is removed");
            })
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log('A file failed to be removed');
            console.log('All files have been successfully removed');
            return res.json(dir);
        })
    });
});
```

front-end:

```
this.rewriteAllFiles = function (files) {
    return $http.post('/emptyDir', { dir: prefix + idP + "/" })
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log("emptyDir finished");
            ...
```

I run a test with a folder that contains 2 files. It first displays nothing in the browser log and the following log in back-end:

```
router.post /emptyDir
["index.html","script.js"]
public/tmp/BGMTbU0RbeHdLAMjAAAD/index.html is removed
public/tmp/BGMTbU0RbeHdLAMjAAAD/script.js is removed
```

Then 2 minutes later, it shows `emptyDir finished` in the browser log, and displays once again `router.post /emptyDir` in the background:

```
router.post /emptyDir
[]
All files have been successfully removed
```

I don't understand why `/emptyDir` is called two times, and why it takes so long...

So does anyone know where is wrong?

**Edit 1:** I realise that using `Array.forEach` works at least for my test. But I am not sure if it is **logically correct**. Can the following function return **before** the block of `files.forEach` has finished?

```
router.post('/writeFiles', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.post writeFiles");
    var dir = req.body.dir, files = req.body.files;
    var fs = require('fs');
    files.forEach(function (file) {
        fs.writeFile(dir + file.name, file.body, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log(dir + file.name + " is written");
        })
    });
    console.log("All files have been successfully written");
    return res.json(dir);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlink is async so your whole foreach loop is run "at the same time" than the rest of your code, it's the same for readdir and almost every functions in node that isn't "Sync".

I think you might consider working with Promises. You could create an array of Promises populated for each file you unlink. You'll then wait completion (or failure) of all Promises with Promise.all().

Something similar to this (it would need some "reorganisation" but it's the idea):

```
router.post('/emptyDir', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.post /emptyDir");
    var dir = req.body.dir;
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
        var unlinkQueue = files.map(function(file) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                fs.unlink(dir + file, function (err) {
                    if (err) return reject(err);
                    console.log(dir + file + " is removed");
                    resolve(file);
                });
            });
        });
        Promise.all(unlinkQueue)
            .then(function(files) {
                console.log("All files have been successfully removed");
                res.json(dir);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                /* error */
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise that, compared to [the doc of async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each), I have forgotten the `callback` in `async.each(files, function(file, callback) ...)`. The following code works:

```
router.post('/emptyDir', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("router.post /emptyDir");
    var dir = req.body.dir;
    var fs = require('fs');
    var async = require('async');
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(files));
        async.each(files, function (file, callback) {
            fs.unlink(dir + file, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(dir + file + " is removed");
                    callback();
                }
            })
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log('A file failed to be removed');
            console.log('All files have been successfully removed');
            return res.json(dir);
        })
    });
});
```